# HTC Clock widget takes 2-3 seconds to update after unlock

Tags: app-widgets, clock, htc-one-x

On my HTC One X, my home screen has an HTC Clock widget on it. When I unlock my phone, the time displayed on the clock shows the old time (when the phone was last unlocked) for about 2-3 seconds, and only then updates to the correct time. The system time (as seen on the lock screen and in the status bar) is correct at all times, so for a jarring moment the widget and the status bar are displaying different times.

If I place an HTC Clock widget on a panel other than the home one, a similar problem occurs: the clock is not updated until a few seconds after that panel is displayed, at which time it 'jumps' to the correct time.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Is this a problem unique to the HTC Clock widget, or would this also happen if I used a different app?

*edit* this behaviour remains the same in Airplane mode, so it's not a network latency issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following an OTA upgrade to Android 4.1.1, this problem appears to have been fixed. On unlocking, the clock widget immediately shows the correct system time.

Comment: Im having the same issue on Android 5.0

Answer (score -1):

***From your description ..***

It would appear that the widget is just polling (**ntp** to Internet timeserver), rather than ever trusting the inbuilt (battery backed) clock.

*This could simply be a design decision / flaw.*

Comment: I've just checked, and the behaviour is the same in Airplane mode. Editing question to include this.