# Clock in notification bar slow to update

Tags: clock

Phone : LG G3
Android 5.0

When I open the cover of my phone, the clock in the upper right corner sometimes shows a delay of a couple of minutes for as much as 3 seconds then updates to the correct time.

This has caused my problems when quick looking at the time during classes to see how much time I had left.

Any known fixes?

Comment: Are you stopping any system apps??

Comment: No. And I don't have apps that would do that automatically (to the best of my knowledge(

Comment: Related issue: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30057/htc-clock-widget-takes-2-3-seconds-to-update-after-unlock?rq=1, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75512/clock-frozen-in-the-notification-bar?rq=1, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87089/clock-in-notification-area-does-not-update?rq=1, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/90267/clock-off-by-4-min-even-if-use-network-value-is-on-probably-due-to-an-app?rq=1

Comment: I had already looked at those posts and nothing solves my problem. I will include that info in my original post and will keep that in mind when asking a question again.